# how to combine domain login and intranet login

Tags: single-sign-on

hello friends i am developing one intranet application called human resource information system using jsp and servlets. I want to combine both domain login and application login
I mean when user login to the system using his/her user name he/she will automatically log in to my intranet application how its posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look/google for information on how to implement a "single sign on" or SSO using jsp.

One promising link might be [this (**Build and implement a single sign-on solution**, an IBM page)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-singlesign/)